# Ensure a variable is only at one state at any given time

Tags: python, software-design

Let's say we have a simulation of taxi movements. Each car at any given time, can be only in one of `idle, rebalancing, serving` states (just as an example, there are many more in my simulation). At any time, I have to check the state of each of the vehicles and act accordingly. For example, if a vehicle was idle and then picked up a passenger, its state should change from `idle` to `serving`. Importantly, at any given time the vehicle can only be in one of those states and its action set is also dependent on that state.

Currently, I am doing this with a long list of `if-else` checks, but feels very naive and it's very difficult to debug. 
For example, the main logic checks the state of a car first:

```
    if self.should_move():


        _ = _make_a_decision(t)
        self.update_rebalancing(WARMUP_PHASE)



    if self.is_busy():
        self.keep_serving()

    elif self.is_waiting_to_be_matched():
        # it's sitting somewhere
        self.keep_waiting()




    elif self.rebalancing:  # and not self.busy:
        self.update_rebalancing(WARMUP_PHASE)
```

Then any of those functions update its state accordingly, all including statements like this

```
    self.idle = False
    self.rebalancing = False
    self.serving = True
    self.time_idled = 0
```

There is a lot of repetition and easy to make mistakes.

I am wondering if

1. there is a programming pattern for this situation
2. If Python specifically has functionalities to handle this case

Comment: Without seeing the full class definition it's a little hard to follow what's happening, but why not just have an attribute called `state` and have the methods update the `state` attribute?

Comment: If you use a single `state` attribute, then you could make use of a State Transition Table.

Comment: Thank you all. I feel kinda bad that I didn't think of this myself, but this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really broad question and there's not any correct answer to it..

But to try to help, why not use a class?

```
class Taxi:
    # One variable to hold an enum of the states.
    self.state = 'idle'

    # function to update the state
    def setState(self, state):
        self.state = state

    # Functions to check the state (could have one to get the state and check later
    def isIdle(self):
        return self.state == 'idle'
```

Then any functionality the taxi needs to do can be put in the class like:

```
    def pickupPassengers():
        if self.state != 'idle':
            return

        self.passengers += 1
```

Then you create your taxis and manage them through the class

```
taxi1 = Taxi()
taxi1.getPassengers()
```

Comment: I agree, but I would probably make the `pickup_passengers` method raise an exception if it called on a Taxi that isn't in the `idle` state. That lets you avoid a whole lot of edge cases and test failures like "how did this Taxi end up with 43,000 passengers?"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish what you want. Since it can get confusing if you have to manually change multiple variables every time you have a state change... just have one variable in charge of the state! If you want to still be able to refer to `Taxi.idle`, `Taxi.rebalancing`, etc, then you can create `@property` methods. They look like functions when you define them but are called like properties.

See the example below for a `Taxi` class which has only one state variable, `self._state` and uses `@property` methods to return the status.

````py
class Taxi:
    def __init__(self, initial_state = "idle"):
        self._state = initial_state


    @property
    def idle(self):
        return self._state == "idle"

    @property
    def rebalancing(self):
        return self._state == "rebalancing"

    @property
    def serving(self):
        return self._state == "serving"

    def serve(self):
        print("\nChanging state to serving\n")
        self._state = "serving"

T = Taxi() # Initialize taxi

print(f"Taxi is idle: {T.idle}")
print(f"Taxi is rebalancing: {T.rebalancing}")
print(f"Taxi is serving: {T.serving}")

T.serve()

print(f"Taxi is idle: {T.idle}")
print(f"Taxi is rebalancing: {T.rebalancing}")
print(f"Taxi is serving: {T.serving}")```
````

```
Output:

Taxi is idle: True
Taxi is rebalancing: False
Taxi is serving: False

Changing state to serving

Taxi is idle: False
Taxi is rebalancing: False
Taxi is serving: True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially for the @property, it is very handy and helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your design problem is that you're trying to use a series of Booleans to embody one-hot encoding of a discrete variable (state).  If you want only *one* value at a time, the natural way to do this is with a single variable.  Enumeration types are what most advanced languages use for this.  For instance, you can encode "idle" as 0, "rebalancing" as 1, etc.

Python code would look something like this:

```
from enum import Enum, unique, auto    

@unique
class TaxiState(Enum):

    IDLE  = auto()
    REBAL = auto()
    SERVE = auto()


class Taxi():

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = TaxiState.IDLE 

    def is_busy(self):
        return self.state != TaxiState.IDLE
```

You don't worry about the coding; `auto` handles that.  All you do is use the enumeration name as a value.  You get to code just as you designed that aspect of the model.

Comment: Where does `auto` come from? Running this gives me a NameError saying auto is not defined

Comment: Ah -- it appears that `auto` wasn't carried forward into the latest Python versions.  Fixing ...

Comment: Is `from enum import auto` not what you're looking for? https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values

Comment: Ah ... it *did* carry forward.  Thanks!

Comment: Use it in good health.  When I was in grad school (computer programming on clay tablets), we had to hand-code our own enumeration sequences for hand-built state machines.  Things are better now.